# Crashing in -dealloc with message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, crash

Whenever I build and run I get no errors or warnings. Then I tried setting `NSZombieEnabled`. I get the following crash:

> 2011-12-06 16:08:46.869 APITextProject[4194:207] *** -[APITextProjectViewController dealloc]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5a31480

Here is my code:

```
#pragma ASI Delegate methods
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSLog(@"Request finished successfully");
    NSLog(@"%@",[request responseString]);

    NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [[request responseString]JSONValue];
    NSDictionary *arrayElement = [responseDictionary objectForKey:@"user"];

    NSString *ID = [arrayElement valueForKeyPath:@"id"];
    NSLog(@"id: %d",ID);
    NSString *usr = [arrayElement valueForKeyPath:@"usr"];
    NSLog(@"usr: %@",usr);
    NSString *gd = [arrayElement valueForKeyPath:@"gd"];
    NSLog(@"gd: %@",gd);
    NSString *age = [arrayElement valueForKeyPath:@"ag"];
    NSLog(@"ag: %@",age);
    NSString *st = [arrayElement valueForKeyPath:@"st"];
    NSLog(@"st: %@",st);
    NSString *lf = [arrayElement valueForKeyPath:@"lf"];
    NSLog(@"lf: %@",lf);
    NSString *da = [arrayElement valueForKeyPath:@"da"];
    NSLog(@"da: %d",da);

    for(NSString *value in [arrayElement allValues]){
        NSLog(@"Found Value %@",value);     
        label.text = value;
        [super release];
    }
}
```

Comment: you crash happens because of APITextProjectViewController instance incorrect use, but your code doesn't show, how you use it

Comment: Have you tried to comment out the `[super release];` in `requestFinished:` method ?

Comment: Thanks for you immediate response guys.... i really appreciated it... THANKS A lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please delete this line.

```
[super release];
```

It should NEVER make sense to call release on super.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir.... can i have one more question?? its about the value im getting only the last element. how can i get all of it in a single label box sir is it possible?

Comment: There are several method on NSString and NSMuteableString to concatenate Strings. i.e.: `string = [string stringByAppendingString:aString]`

Comment: ok sir thanksss. im gonna try it. im so sorry about my question.. im a real noob thanks again

Comment: Note that `[super release]` is exactly equivalent to `[self release]` (unless for some crazy reason `release` has been overridden).

Comment: @vikingosegundo sir i just want to ask why is the value of da the first one to appear at the app instead of the ID? here is my format:`label.text = [value stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@,%@",ID,usr,gd,ag,st,lf,da];`

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling your problem lies in the line `[super release]` inside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling `[super release]` in your request delegate method? Why would you ever call super release?

Comment: I have seen it several times in Singletons — but definitely wrong, too